# Please help me out with this python code

Tags: python

The aim of the program is to generate an anagram given 6 randomly generated alphabets.the syntax seems to be correct but there's some sort of logical error which i am not able to figure out.If you execute the program then it will just go on running,& wont stop.I don't think its because of any infinite loop,rather its due t its inability to find anagram using the 6 generated letters.Maybe,i made a dumb mistake,but please point it out.I have highlighted the portion where i think there is error.I will be glad if u could help me out.
The file words.txt can be downloaded from http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt

```
import random

def game():

  while True:
    ch=[]
    res=[]  
    print 'The 6 randomly generated alphabets are :'
    for i in range(6):
       ch.append(chr(random.randrange(97,123)))
    print ch,'\n'
    delimiter=''
    z=delimiter.join(ch)                     #converted list to a string
    word_list2=dict()                        #word_list2 is a dictionary containing randomly generated letters as keys 
    for c in z:
      if c not in word_list2:
        word_list2[c]=1
      else:
        word_list2[c]=word_list2[c]+1

    fin=open('words.txt')
    for c in range(130000):
        words=fin.readline()
        word=words.strip()
        flag=1
        if len(word)==6:

            word_list1=dict()                 #word_list1 is a dict containing char present in word as keys

            for c in word:
                if c not in word_list1:
                    word_list1[c]=1
                else:
                    word_list1[c]=word_list1[c]+1

            ***for c in word_list2:
                if c not in word_list1:
                  flag=1                                  
                  break
                else:
                    if word_list1[c]==word_list2[c]:                #comparing if characters in both dict have same no. i.e 'a' should occur 2 times in both etc
                      flag==0
                    else:
                      flag=1
                      break***



        if flag==0:
          res.append(word)

    if not res:
        print 'the list is empty'
        print 'Selecting a new set of randomly generated characters\n'

    else :
        print res
        break

game()
```

Comment: I would suggest you find a minimal example of where the code is "failing", so that we can take a clearer look at it. Have you tried deleting blocks of code strategically, or printing traces every few lines?

Comment: Since you have a `while True` loop, and you're reporting that it's not terminating, you need to get a look at the program as it runs. One way to do this is to manually trace through the execution of the code and try to figure it out. Another is to insert some print statements at key points so you can watch the program as it executes.

Comment: This is another variation of the code ! Its working just fine

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it.....Thanks for your help guys.Here's the code that works

```
def is_anagram(s,t):
    x=dict()
    y=dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in x:
            x[c]=1
        else:
            x[c]=x[c]+1
    for c in t:
        if c not in y:
            y[c]=1
        else:
            y[c]=y[c]+1

    for c in x:
        if c not in y:
            flag=1
            break
        else:
            if x[c]==y[c]:

                flag=0
            else:
                flag=1
                break
    if flag==0:

        return 0
    else:

        return 1

import random

def game():

  while True:
    ch=[]
    res=[]  
    print 'The 6 randomly generated alphabets are :'
    for i in range(6):
       ch.append(chr(random.randrange(97,123)))
    print ch,'\n'
    delimiter=''
    z=delimiter.join(ch)                     #converted list to a string

    fin=open('words.txt')
    for c in range(130000):
        val=1
        words=fin.readline()
        word=words.strip()
        flag=1
        if len(word)==6:

            val=is_anagram(z,word)



        if val==0:
          res.append(word)

    if not res:
        print 'the list is empty'
        print 'Selecting a new set of randomly generated characters\n'

    else :
        print res
        break

game()
```